# Inserting into a different table from a form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to make an event when iputing data in a form on access, after the text box looses focus, if the box is not null I want the ID and the value to get stored into another table. After trying with the code below I get "Runtime error 3061 Too few parameters Expected 1". I have checked in debug mode and the values are getting carried over and brought to the string.

```
Private Sub Consolidate_LostFocus()
Dim queryString As String
queryString = "INSERT INTO [ReportMasterTable]([#], [Notes]) VALUES(" & [#].Value & ", " &   [Consolidate].Value & ")"

If Consolidate.Text <> vbNullString Then

    CurrentDb.Execute (queryString)

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why has no one mentioned this code is begging for an injection attack (in fact the question basically says it already has an injection issue just with the regular data.)

Comment: It's only a small in house DB, we're only using it for a few weeks for some analysis

Comment: and if you had used a parameterized query then you would not even be asking this question because there would not be this delimiter problem.  Doing it right is doing it right.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your criticism. I did not know you could parameterize queries in access, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Access parameter queries are fairly simple to create and use.  The example I gave you will likely run without error as written.  Give it a try; discard it if you don't like it.

Comment: A parameter query may be an idea, but there are far more problems here that that. This form should probably not include SQL at all, it should be bound to a table or query. In this case, parameters are a red-herring masking real design problems. It is pointing out a cut finger to a person with a broken leg. That is why @Hogan, I did not mention parameters.

Comment: Note that while parameter queries have their uses in Access, you cannot use DAO to update memo data type. For the most part, you should avaoid parameters in MS Access by using forms.

Comment: @Remou - I guess we need to agree to disagree; a level of indirection (ie databound) does not change the design that much, but not using parameterized queries or stored procedures has a big impact in terms of maintainability, stability and security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you do not wish ti bind the form to the ReportMasterTable?

If you really have a control and field called #, you are facing a world of trouble.

If you have bound the form to ReportMasterTable and are also updating in a query, you are going to run into problems.

The lost focus event is a very bad event to choose, any time anyone tabs through the form, the code will run. After update would be better.

You are updating a text data type, but you have not used quotes.

```
"INSERT INTO [ReportMasterTable]([#], [Notes]) VALUES(" & [#].Value _
    & ", '" &   [Consolidate].Value & "')"
```

Comment: I didn't make the names, a co-worker did. I have to work with what I have

Comment: I am not blaming you, but these particular names are delimiters, so I would strongly advise you to change them as soon as possible, even if you just use a query and alias for now.

Comment: Thank you I plan on changing them. This is what happens when your PM designs your db lol

Answer (score 3):

If either the `#` or the `Notes` fields in `ReportMasterTable` is text data type, you must add quotes around the values you attempt to `INSERT`.

For example, if *both* fields are text type:

```vba
queryString = "INSERT INTO [ReportMasterTable]([#], [Notes])" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES ('" & [#].Value & "', '" & [Consolidate].Value & "')"
```

The situation will be more complicated if either `[#].Value` or `[Consolidate].Value` contains a single quote.  You could double up the single quotes within the inserted values.  However it might be easier to just switch to a parameterized query ... the quoting problem would go away.

```vba
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "PARAMETERS hash_sign Text (255), note_value Text (255);" & vbCrLf & _
    "INSERT INTO [ReportMasterTable]([#], [Notes])" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES (hash_sign, note_value)"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("hash_sign").value = Me.[#]
qdf.Parameters("note_value").value = Me.[consolidate]
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

You could also save the SQL statement as a named query and open and execute that instead of rebuilding the statement every time your procedure runs.